# How do I get hyphens in my attribute names in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, hyphenation

Flex has an issue with hyphens in xml. I need to generate an xml object with hyphens in the attribute for a Google Checkout implementation.

I can get away with:

```
var xml:XML = <item-description/>;
```

and

```
var xml:XML = <item-description the-name="foo"/>;
```

but what I need to do is set the value of an attribute like this:

```
var timestamp:String = methodToGetMyTimestampString();

var xml:XML = <item-desc/>;
xml@start-date = timestamp;
```

but I can't do that. Since flex doesn't like the hyphens, I don't know how to get or set attributes with hyphens in the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
xml.attribute("start-date") = timestamp;
```

or

```
xml.@["start-date"] = timestamp;
```

Comment: It won't allow you to make assignments that way.

Comment: Indeed, posted another attempt.

Comment: Thanks Christophe, that second suggestion was it.